# d3 tree graph zooming is only on node

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph

somebody know why the zoom function only trigger when i am over the node and not over the svg? I want that the zoom function tigger when the mouse is over the svg not only over the node. It would be very nice if somebody can help me. Maybe somebody knows how to add pan to graph? To pan the graph has not the highest priority. To zoom the graph is more important.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azu50eo1/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// DATA is a JSON objekt --> see in fiddle
  let data = DATA                   
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 120,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 120
    },
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
      return [d.y, d.x];
    });

  var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom);

  function zoom() {
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log("zoom is only on node?");
    console.log('====================================');
  }

  var svg = d3.select("#tree-svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoomListener)
  draw(data)
  function draw(data) {
    //if (error) throw error;
    let flare = data
    root = flare;
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }
    }

    root.children.forEach(collapse);
    update(root);
  }

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
  function update(source) {
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
      });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click", click);


    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });
    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill", "black");

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
      });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x0,
          y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {
          x: source.x,
          y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
          source: o,
          target: o
        });
      })
      .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {

    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom listener can act upon.

```
var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", viewerWidth)
    .attr("height", viewerHeight)
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .call(zoomListener);

function zoom() {
    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

See this example http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033. Pan is shown on there as well.

Comment: the example from robschmuecker is a little bit buggy. Sometimes the circle goes away.... but thanks :)

Comment: and i dont understand the code :( Maybe somebody has another solution?

Comment: in my code there is a zoomListener too. But it still does not work

Comment: which part don't you understand? did you try grouping as shown above?